# How can I identify portions of a string with Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract a portion of a string based on a consistent pattern. For example, take the following photo caption:

> In this (aerial) photo, a wildfire consumes a tree in a burning forest
>   near Omak, Wash., on  Thursday, Aug. 20, 2015. Firefighters on several
>   fronts are fighting against raging wildfires advancing on towns in the
>   north-central part of the state.  (Bettina Hansen/The Seattle Times
>   via AP)

I want to extract the photo credit in the parenthesis at the end. I know that portion always begins with a "(" and ends with "via AP)".

I tried this:

```
\(.*via AP\)
```

but it selects everything from the first parenthesis (in front of the word aerial) all the way to the last parenthesis. How can I just grab the portion between the parenthesis that ends with "via AP"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `.*` construct is greedy and will happily match *anything* including other opening parenthesis. In the shown input this starts matching at "(aerial" and complete the match on the *last* occurrence of "via AP)" after successfully matching everything in-between.

To fix this use a more refined and thus less-greedy construct:

```
\([^()]*via AP\)
```

This will match an open parenthesis character and then any characters *except* another parenthesis before it matches "via AP". The `[^..]` construct is a negated character class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation... makes total sense. I removed the last bracket (after AP) from your construct to make it work though.